# Identification of power connector for LED panels

Tags: power-supply, connector, identification, led-matrix

We bought a bunch of 32x32 (6mm LED pitch) LED panels from a Shenzen company and some of the power cables were missing, so I'm currently trying to identify them.
Attached are some images.

We think it might be Molex or JST but not sure. The Chinese company contact offers to sell the missing ones to us at outrageous shipping and toll.

Price negotiations => sudden loss of English language skills ;)

I know there are quite some possibilities out there, but can anyone help to unambiguously identify them, so we can try to find them over here (Germany)?

[image: The full cable with both ends]
[image: The connector]
[image: Highly professional depiction of measurements]

Comment: Looks JST. What’s the center to center pin spacing?

Comment: @winny 4 mm in the drawing

Comment: Yes, its 4mm in our highly professional drawing ;)

Comment: Its really hard to identify. Found this stuff: http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eVH.pdf and looks like it could also be 3,96mm pitch. Darn. How can we unmistakenly identify this baby, given the sum of its features? Or is the information I have simply not enough to boil it down to exactly one?

Comment: 3.96mm is ~1% that's probably well within tolerances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the picture and measurements, the connector appears to be a [VHR-4M](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-4M/455-3990-ND/9924201) from JST. Here is a link to the datasheet if you want to verify specifications. 
http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eVH.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: Confirmed! Thanks a lot. It is indeed a JST VHR-4N.